# Factory pattern with interface, how to avoid cast

Tags: c#, generics, interface, factory

I try to implement factory pattern with interface for create different type of Response, but I don't know if I'm doing it right. When I call my method `SetExceptionResponse` with factory class, I must to cast it.

Interface :

```
public interface IResponse
    {
        int ErrorCode { get; set; }

        HeaderResponse HeaderResponse { get; set; }

        IResponse SetExceptionResponse(int code, string title, string[] errors);
    }
```

Main class :

```
    public class Response : IResponse 
    {
        public int ErrorCode { get ; set ; }

        public HeaderResponse HeaderResponse { get; set; } = null;

        public virtual IResponse SetExceptionResponse(int code, string title, string[] errors)
        {
            HeaderResponse headerResponse = new HeaderResponse();
            if (errors.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (string item in errors)
                    headerResponse.ErrorList.Add(item);
            }
            headerResponse.Title = title;
            headerResponse.StatusCode = code;

            return new Response
            {
                ErrorCode = code,
                HeaderResponse = headerResponse
            };
        }
    }
```

Other class who herits main class:

```
public class DeleteShipmentResponse : Response
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        }

        public override IResponse SetExceptionResponse(int code, string title, string[] errors)
        {
            HeaderResponse headerResponse = new HeaderResponse();
            if (errors.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (string item in errors)
                    headerResponse.ErrorList.Add(item);
            }
            headerResponse.Title = title;
            headerResponse.StatusCode = code;

            return new DeleteShipmentResponse
            {
                ErrorCode = code,
                HeaderResponse = headerResponse
            };
        }
```

My factory class :

```
public static class ResponseFactory
    {
        public static IResponse CreateResponse()
        {
            return new Response();
        }

        public static IResponse CreateDeleteResponse()
        {
            return new DeleteShipmentResponse();
        }

        public static IResponse CreateShipmentResponse()
        {
            return new ShipmentResponse();
        }

        public static T CreateResponse<T>()
        where T : IResponse
        {
            return (T)CreateResponse(typeof(T));
        }

        public static IResponse CreateResponse(Type type) 
        {
            if (type == typeof(Response))
                return CreateResponse();
            if (type == typeof(DeleteShipmentResponse))
                return CreateDeleteResponse();
            else if (type == typeof(ShipmentResponse))
                return CreateShipmentResponse();
            else
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Unrecognized type [{0}]", type.FullName), "type");
        }
    }
```

So, when I use factory to create DeleteShipmentResponse and call SetExeceptionResponse I do this :

```
DeleteShipmentResponse result = (DeleteShipmentResponse)ResponseFactory.CreateResponse<DeleteShipmentResponse>().SetExceptionResponse(500, "Exception in DeleteShipment()", new string[] { ex.Message });
```

I must cast with DeleteShipmentResponse otherwise cast exception throw.

How do I get this without typecasting to DeleteShipmentResponse ?
Do I have to use generic interface ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Why something named SetYX in class X returns X ? why you not use just `ResponseFactory.CreateResponse<T>(int code, string title, string[] errors)`  ? ... why not just simple `public Response<T>
    {
        int ErrorCode { get; set; } bool Success ... some other common props .... public T Data {get;set;}`

Comment: I don't see the benefit of the factory in this case. You could just delete the factory class and wherever you were calling `ResponseFactory.CreateDeleteResponse()` just call `new DeleteResponse()` instead. If you did that, the essence of your question would still remain, which suggests that this factory class is not central to your question. It's obscuring the question. Even if you keep it in your code I'd remove it from the question because it's not relevant and makes it harder to follow.

Comment: @ScottHannen you're right, I think I like to complicate my life ^^. I don't kown why I do this.

Comment: It's what we do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is ok for all `IResponse`'s to have a parameterless constructor, you can make `IResponse` generic "of itself", i.e. with `T` constrained to `IResponse<T>`:

```
public interface IResponse<T> where T : IResponse<T>
{
    int ErrorCode { get; set; }

    HeaderResponse HeaderResponse { get; set; }

    T SetExceptionResponse(int code, string title, string[] errors);
}

public class Response<T> : IResponse<T> where T : IResponse<T>, new
{
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }

    public HeaderResponse HeaderResponse { get; set; } = null;
    public virtual T SetExceptionResponse(int code, string title, string[] errors)
    {
        HeaderResponse headerResponse = new HeaderResponse();
        .....    
        return new T
        {
            ErrorCode = code,
            HeaderResponse = headerResponse
        };
    }
}

public class DeleteShipmentResponse : Response<DeleteShipmentResponse>
{
    ...

    public override DeleteShipmentResponse SetExceptionResponse(int code, string title, string[] errors)
    {
        ....
        return new DeleteShipmentResponse
        {
            ErrorCode = code,
            HeaderResponse = headerResponse
        };
    }
}
```